# Making shapes with linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

For an assignment, I'm trying to make a shell script that will print a triangle that looks like the following:

```
+
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
+-----
```

Here is my code in VIM:

```
echo'+
     | \
     |  \
     |   \
     |    \
     +----- '
```

However, instead of getting that as the output when I run the script, it outputs as the following:

[image: VI output issue]

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really not have a space after `echo`? You should be getting an error message from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '
     +
     | \
     |  \
     |   \
     |    \
     +----- '
```

just start it on the next line since you need spaces before the "+"

Comment: Oh my God. It's always the little things like that which kill me in programming. That did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How did your output got merged to 3 lines?
I think your original command was with a space after `echo` and double quotes:

```
echo "+
     | \
     |  \
     |   \
     |    \
     +----- "
```

And now pay attention to the last character of each line. When the last character is the `\`, the following line is appended to the current line.
Make sure each line ends with a space (or use single quotes).