# Hypotenuse From Shell Script Linux

Tags: linux, shell

This is related to my previous question:
[Making shapes with linux shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758416/making-shapes-with-linux-shell-script)

I'm trying to write a shell script program with VIM that given sides A and B of the Pythagorean Theorem, it will provide C. Here is my code:

```
echo -n "Enter A: "
read A
echo -n "Enter B: "
read B
BSquared=$(($B**2))
ASquared=$((A**2))
CSquared=$(($B+$A))
Hypot='echo"scale=2;sqrt($CSquared)"|bc'
echo '
  +
  |\
  | \ C
A |  \
  |   \
  +----
    B    '

 echo "A = $A"
 echo "B = $B"
 echo "C = $Hypot"
```

The triangle part is just for fun. The only thing wrong with my script is that on the line:

```
echo "C = $Hypot"
```

The output is as follows:

```
C = "scale=2;sqrt($CSquared)"|bc
```

In other words, the code from the script. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable equal to the output from a command in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: Why did you included vim here? Are you okay with solution in vimscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), you must use backticks or `$()` syntax, not single quotes.

You must also separate the `echo` command from its argument by adding a space after it.

Replace:

```
Hypot='echo"scale=2;sqrt($CSquared)"|bc'
```

with:

```
Hypot=`echo "scale=2;sqrt($CSquared)"|bc`
```

or for better readability :

```
Hypot=$(echo "scale=2;sqrt($CSquared)"|bc)
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the shell is **bash**, there's no need for **echo**:

```
Hypot=$(bc <<< "scale=2;sqrt($CSquared)")
```